# I need to use an Electron app, but it keeps maxing out my CPU

Tags: linux, cpu, performance, electron

I am on a low end AMD laptop running a chip described in `/proc/cpuinfo` as an `AMD Ryzen 3 3250U with Radeon Graphics`. I'm also running my Linux system off of a pen drive modified for persistence (don't ask why :-)). This means my I/O speeds are quite slow, as compared to any normal system.

To address the slow I/O speeds I run [profile-sync-daemon](https://github.com/graysky2/profile-sync-daemon) and [anything-sync-daemon](https://github.com/graysky2/anything-sync-daemon). I use the former to ensure the profile and cache directories of my Firefox install are in a RAM disk, and I use the latter to ensure that the cache and config directories of my [Franz](https://www.meetfranz.com) install are also in a RAM disk.

The problem occurs with the latter application, Franz. I use it to access WhatsApp, which I need to do quite frequently, and there's no WhatsApp desktop app for Linux.  Franz is an Electron app, as far as I can tell. Even after ASD should ostensibly be making sure that slow I/O isn't bothering Franz, though, Franz regularly maxes out my CPU when it is running - leading to freezes, slowdowns, etc.  Sometimes Firefox seems to do this too, but mostly it's Franz.

I've tried running Franz with `nice -n +12 Franz` to give it a lower priority, but this seems to make at most a marginal difference.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the frequency with which Franz does this?  I should also say that the few times I have run my pen drive on a more powerful system - an older Intel i5 laptop - the same thing has happened there as well.

Comment: A way to eliminate and isolate the cause of this poor performance is to install Visual Studio Code, if that application does not cause the same behavior, then the performance problems is a combination of the application itself and your setup. Booting of a flash media storage device likely has something to do with the poor performance

Answer (score 1):

[Franz Support](https://meetfranz.com/support#service-hibernation)
has this advice :

> **Franz is consuming a lot of CPU and working memory. Is there anything I can do about it?**
>
> In our latest version (Franz 5.5.0) we introduced a service
> hibernation feature to reduce the energy consumption. You can enable
> hibernation for each service individually.
>
> Additionally, we recommend to disable the option 'Keep all workspaces
> loaded' in your general settings.

Comment: Franz 5.5 has been out since 2020. You likely simply missed the quoted text.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't know if this fix was truly incorporated in Franz, even today, or that the problem was really solved if it was incorporated. There was however an advice in the text that I thought might be useful.

Comment: @harrymc As it turns out, it did not seem to make much difference.  For the moment I don't have much more to report as I've switched to using a Chromium web app (running with `profile-sync-daemon` to minimise IO) for accessing WhatsApp instead, which seems to work far better. But I'll try out Franz again soon, I'm sure, and will look for more fixes then